# symfony update database without ssh access

Tags: symfony, ssh, deployment

I try to update database schema of a web site online but I don't have SSH access. I only have FTP access and the projet locally in my pc.

How can I do ? Thanks.

Comment: If you have the project locally, you can create a .sql file with the updates and load that in PHPMyAdmin. Or run the update command from inside a controller

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll copie the online databas locally, update it and laod it in PHPMyAdmin

Answer (score 1):

Symfony allows you to run commands from controller.
So apparently you can jus run doctine:schema:update from controller action.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/console/command_in_controller.html

Comment: Thanks for the documentation.